# Searching for all repositories with *.yml files with GitHub GraphQL

Tags: github, graphql

I want to find all repositories in an organization that have workflow files in use for further analysis.

I can run a search through GraphQL for a specific file if I now its name:

```
{
  search(query: "org:rajbos", type: REPOSITORY, last: 100) {
    repositoryCount
    pageInfo {
      endCursor
      startCursor
    }
    edges {
      node{
        ... on Repository {
          nameWithOwner
          url
          object(expression: "HEAD:README.md") {
            ... on Blob {
              byteSize
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do I search for a *.yml file in a specific directory? I don't know the filenames up front.

repository(owner:"someOwner", name:"some-Repo")

Answer (score 1):

Found that you can query all repositories for files at a location, then filter that set clientside:

```
query {
 search(first: 100, type: REPOSITORY, query: "org:rajbos") {
   repositoryCount
    edges {       
      node {
        ... on Repository {  
          nameWithOwner
          object(expression: "main:.github/workflows/") {
            ... on Tree {
              entries {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
 {
          "node": {
            "nameWithOwner": "rajbos/github-fork-updater",
            "object": {
              "entries": [
                {
                  "name": "check-workflow.yml"
                },
                {
                  "name": "update-workflow.yml"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Note: this doesnt give you any forks, since those are not available in the Repository objects :-(